# Unable to select more than one object in Edit Mode

Tags: objects

I have created 6 cubes in Object Mode and I can select each of them individually or by box selecting. However when I tab into Edit Mode I am only able to select the last one selected in Object Mode. The remaining 5 cubes will not select. This behaviour is same when trying to select Vertices, Edges or Faces. When I return to Object Mode and change the selection then go back into Edit Mode the object I had been previously able to select will not do so and it is only the one I last selected in Object Mode that will select.

Been on this for hours now and would love some suggestions of thins to try

Additional: I found that I could select the meshes if I added them when in edit mode from the add tab. However, The final 3 meshes all ended up sharing a point of origin which I had not deliberately done. When I deleted them and then went into the Object Mode I could no longer return to the Edit Mode!! I am now as I hit the Undo keys several times.

Been working with Blender for several days now and was enjoying it. Personally this doesn't now feel like a stable release to me!

Comment: I may not understand what you mean, but its normal to not be able to change your object selection in edit mode. The general workflow is to select the objects you want to edit, then go into edit mode to modify those selected objects, then return to object mode to change your selection.

Comment: in 2.7 you can select several objects in Object mode but only the last selected will be editable in Edit mode. In 2.8 you can select several objects in Object mode and there will be all editable in Edit mode. So if you're in 2.8 it's weird that you can't edit several objects.

Comment: @Robert. Thank you for taking the trouble to help out. I realise that I was expecting too much but I had felt that I had been selecting back and forth while remaining in Edit Mode so it completely fooled me and, to be honest, I thought I had something I shouldn't have. I have been happy blending away now that I know my set-up is working as it should so thanks again for your help it is greatly appreciated

Comment: @moonboots. Thank you for taking the trouble to help out. I realise that I was expecting too much but I had felt that I had been selecting back and forth while remaining in Edit Mode so it completely fooled me and, to be honest, I thought I had something I shouldn't have. I have been happy blending away now that I know my set-up is working as it should so thanks again for your help it is greatly appreciated

Comment: @MainFrameHax. Thank you for taking the trouble to help out. I realise that I was expecting too much but I had felt that I had been selecting back and forth while remaining in Edit Mode so it completely fooled me and, to be honest, I thought I had something I shouldn't have. I have been happy blending away now that I know my set-up is working as it should so thanks again for your help it is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think I know what you are looking for.

Edit mode allows you to modify the geometry of a single object. Edit mode is based on the selected object and allows direct modifications of the mesh of the selected object. This means that if no object is selected, you can't go into edit mode. This also means that adding meshes in edit mode adds disconnected edges and faces to the selected object, and does not add an independent object.

Object modes allows translation of different independent objects while almost all of the other modes in viewport allow manipulation of the selected object.

To point out some things; meshes can be separated from an object using "p" (either though selection, material, or loose parts), origins can be reset by right clicking and selecting set origin, and then selecting the option that applies to your situation, and edit mode can be quickly toggled using tab.

If you want to be able to edit the meshes of multiple objects at once, you have to switch out of edit mode for that object, select a new object, and then enter edit mode for the new object. I recommend watching some tutorials on youtube as they can do a great job of explaining how objects and meshes work in blender.